# PRESTASHOP NGINX + REWRITE RULES

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've being searching for a good solution for this combination and after following these:

1. http://www.phamviet.net/2012/06/03/prestashop-rewrite-url-on-nginx/
2. [Nginx configuration for Prestashop](http://www.nginxtips.com/nginx-configuration-for-prestashop/)
3. [Prestashop 1.5.6.2 rewrite URLs over nginx install](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/307168-prestashop-1562-rewrite-urls-over-nginx-install/?hl=%2Bnginx#entry1554501)

none of them seemed to work for me at all... so I started experimenting:

After configuring SSL, CloudFlare, etc....

This is what I tried:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysuperdomain.com www.mysuperdomain.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  # listen 80 deferred; # for Linux
  # listen 80 accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD
  listen 443;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name mysuperdomain.com *.mysuperdomain.com;

  # Path for static files
  root /sites/mysuperdomain.com/public;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;

  # Try static files first, then php
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  # Specific logs for this vhost
  access_log /sites/mysuperdomain.com/log/log-access.log;
  error_log  /sites/mysuperdomain.com/log/log-error.log error;

  #Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

  # Redirect needed to "hide" index.php
  location / {
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$1$2$3.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg break;
    if (-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location /c {
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1$2$3.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/$1$2.jpg break;
}
location /images_ie {
    rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 break;
}

# Don't log robots.txt or favicon.ico files
location ~* ^/(favicon.ico|robots.txt)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
# Custom 404 page
error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

location ~* ^.+.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|htm|html|js|css|mp3|swf|ico|flv|xml) {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# Deny access to .htaccess
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

#PHPMYADMIN
location /phpmyadmin {
 root /usr/share/;
 index index.php index.html index.htm;
 location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   root /usr/share/;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|css|gif|ico|js|html|xml|txt))$ {
   root /usr/share/;
}
}
location /phpMyAdmin {
 rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}

# Include the basic h5bp config set
include h5bp/basic.conf;
}
```

It seems to only work for categories but not for individual products pages and such.

When you hit the main domain or go to the home page, it will download index.php instead of showing the home page.

So a little bit of help would be amazing!

Comment: what do you mean by "this is my first post"?  I see 13 other questions by you...

Comment: bad copy/paste , I'm sorry , I just remove the lines, because this post was for Server Fault, but Server Fault is for more experimented people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working for me perfectly:

```
server {
  fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
  listen  80;
  listen  443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

  error_log /srv/example.com/log/error.log;
  root /srv/example.com/html;

  location / {
      index index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
      access_log        off;
      log_not_found     off;
      expires           360d;
  }

  location ~ /\. {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off; 
      deny all;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
      allow all;
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9010;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/example.com/html$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE max_execution_time=180;
  }

  # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
  location ~ /\. {
      deny all;
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
  }

  rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;

  rewrite "^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(.*)\.jpg$" /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/c/([_a-zA-Z-]+)/(.*)\.jpg$" /img/c/$1.jpg last;

  rewrite "^/([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1-$2.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;

  rewrite "^/([0-9]+)\-(\P{M}\p{M}*)+\.html(.*)$" /index.php?controller=product&id_product=$1$3 last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=category&id_category=$1$3 last;
  rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html(.*)$" /index.php?controller=product&id_product=$2$4 last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=supplier&id_supplier=$1$3 last;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=manufacturer&id_manufacturer=$1$3 last;
  rewrite "^/content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=cms&id_cms=$1$3 last;
  rewrite "^/content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=cms&id_cms_category=$1$3 last;
  rewrite "^/module/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$" /index.php?fc=module&module=$1&controller=$2 last;

  rewrite ^/page-not-found$ /index.php?controller=404 last;
  rewrite ^/address$ /index.php?controller=address last;  
  rewrite ^/addresses$ /index.php?controller=addresses last;
  rewrite ^/authentication$ /index.php?controller=authentication last;
  rewrite ^/best-sales$ /index.php?controller=best-sales last;
  rewrite ^/cart$ /index.php?controller=cart last;
  rewrite ^/contact-us$ /index.php?controller=contact-form last;
  rewrite ^/discount$ /index.php?controller=discount last;
  rewrite ^/guest-tracking$ /index.php?controller=guest-tracking last;
  rewrite ^/order-history$ /index.php?controller=history last;
  rewrite ^/identity$ /index.php?controller=identity last;
  rewrite ^/manufacturers$ /index.php?controller=manufacturer last;
  rewrite ^/my-account$ /index.php?controller=my-account last;
  rewrite ^/new-products$ /index.php?controller=new-products last;
  rewrite ^/order$ /index.php?controller=order last;
  rewrite ^/order-follow$ /index.php?controller=order-follow last;
  rewrite ^/quick-order$ /index.php?controller=order-opc last;
  rewrite ^/order-slip$ /index.php?controller=order-slip last;
  rewrite ^/password-recovery$ /index.php?controller=password last;
  rewrite ^/prices-drop$ /index.php?controller=prices-drop last;  
  rewrite ^/search$ /index.php?controller=search last;
  rewrite ^/sitemap$ /index.php?controller=sitemap last;
  rewrite ^/stores$ /index.php?controller=stores last;  
  rewrite ^/supplier$ /index.php?controller=supplier last;

  location ~* \.(gif)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
  }

  location ~* \.(png)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
  }

  location ~* \.(css)$ {
    expires 604800s;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|jsonp)$ {
    expires 604800s;
  }

  location ~* \.(js)$ {
    expires 604800s;
  }

  location ~* \.(ico)$ {
    expires 31536000s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That does not work in multilingual sites in 1.6

I found an answer on the prestashop site that works fine but not on multilingual sites.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/System+Administrator+Guide#SystemAdministratorGuide-NginxfriendlyURLs

```
location /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/ {
  index /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/index.php;

  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/api/?(.*)$ /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$     /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$     /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$     /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$     /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$     /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$     /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.jpg$ /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/c/$1.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/index.php?$args;
}
```

change /PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/ to / if in root folder
Note: the code in the link above has a typo so use this code instead.

Comment: This results in 404 on all my images :(

Comment: Same for me. I have multistore running and one store is fine the second one has 404 on images despite me adding the code suggested in the guide. Did anyone solve this? Using prestashop 1.7.5

Answer (score 1):

I have generated rewrites using this SQL: (prestashop 1.6.1.6, nginx 1.10.2)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
 CONCAT('rewrite ^/',`url_rewrite`,'$ /index.php?controller=', `page`,' last;')
FROM `ps_meta` a 
LEFT JOIN `ps_meta_lang` b ON (b.`id_meta` = a.`id_meta` AND b.`id_lang` = 1 AND b.`id_shop` = 1)           
WHERE 1   AND a.configurable = 1  AND url_rewrite != ''
GROUP BY a.id_meta 
ORDER BY a.`id_meta` ASC
```

After paste and reload on nginx, friendly urls works good.

Answer (score 0):

you can add also

```
  rewrite ^/products-comparison$ /index.php?controller=products-comparison last;
```

in the rewrite list ( for Product Comparison Page )