# Prestashop 1.6 + Nginx + SSL + Multilingual Site - Rewrite Rules

Tags: ssl, nginx, multilingual, prestashop-1.6

I am struggling with setting up rewrite rules for prestashop with the following setup

- Prestashop 1.6
- SSL
- Multiligual Site (fr + en in my case)
- Nginx 1.4.1 (that is important for ssl settings I found)

I have used some of the references below

http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/323391-another-nginx-ssl-rewrite-rules-problem/
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/321261-seo-friendly-nginx-rewrites/ (not multilingual)
[PRESTASHOP NGINX + REWRITE RULES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070441/prestashop-nginx-rewrite-rules)

and got to this config below.

Everything works except some of my payment modules which return a url like
mysite.com/en/index.php?parameter1=1&parameter2=2

This triggers a 404

It looks like the url should be rewritten as 
mysite.com/index.php?parameter1=1&parameter2=2

I have two questions:

1. Which rule is handling urls like **mysite.com/en/16-crews** which are working fine?
   and what is it translated to ? (I am just curious to understand how that works)
2. How do I set up a rule to rewrite 
   **mysite.com/en/index.php?parameter1=1&parameter2=2**
   to
   **mysite.com/index.php?parameter1=1&parameter2=2**
   It must also work with the french side of the site **/fr/index.php** to **/index.php**

   ```
   server {

   listen   80;
   listen  443 ssl;
   server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.key;

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;
   rewrite_log on;

   location / {
   root   /srv/d_h2osensations/www/www.mysite.com/htdocs;
   index  index.html index.htm index.php;

   rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg             last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ -            img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$             /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$             /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/d_h2osensations/www/www.mysite.com/htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
   }

   # Deny access to .htaccess
   location ~ /\.ht {
   deny all;
   }

   location /phpmyadmin
   { root /usr/share/;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   root /usr/share/;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
   }
   location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
   root /usr/share/;
   }
   }
   location /phpMyAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;

   }

   }
   ```

Thanks in advance.
Nic

Answer (score 5):

After a few weeks of looking around this is what works for me

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen  443 default ssl;
    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert-key.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/h2o.prod.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/h2o.prod.error.log;



    root /var/www/www.mysite.com/htdocs;
    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;


    #Specify a charset
    charset utf-8;

    rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;

    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;


    rewrite ^/order$ /index.php?controller=order last;
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
    }

    # Redirect needed to "hide" index.php
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```